# Semaphore fail to block thread in Win32 console app

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++

i met a pretty weird issue that : WaitForSingleObject() in windows.h fail to block the thread despite the semaphore has been 0 already.

Here's my code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    MsgQueue mainQueue;

    //WaitForSingleObject(mainQueue.procSema,(DWORD)(INFINITE));

    mainQueue.Enqueue_Back(_T("hello world!"));
    mainQueue.Enqueue_Back(_T("This is the second test line"));
    mainQueue.Enqueue_Back(_T("Here's the third line"));

    TCHAR buffer[256];
    int ct = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        cout<<"Start wait ... "<<ct++<<endl;
        WaitForSingleObject(mainQueue.procSema,(DWORD)(INFINITE));
        memset(buffer,0,256*sizeof(TCHAR));

        mainQueue.Dequeue_Front(buffer,255);
        cout<<buffer<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and i found the semaphore - mainQueue.procSema fail to block the loop even it has been wait to 0 already.

the semaphore is declared and initialized like this:

```
procSema = CreateSemaphore(NULL,(LONG)(0),(LONG)(INFINITE),NULL);
```

and in Each enqueue function, it will be signaled by one

```
ReleaseSemaphore(procSema,(LONG)(1),NULL);
```

i tried to add multiple wait lines before my first enqueue but it still does not work...

help me please ..

Environment:

VC2012 Ult, Windows7 Ult, Start from a empty project

Comment: You should check the return value from `WaitForSingleObject()`.

Comment: Capture the return value of WaitForSingleObject. It has 4 possible values as documented here. That will tell you what signaled the WaitForSingleObject method. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @MatsPetersson Sorry for repeating your answer, you already posted by the time I went to fetch the MSDN link :)

Comment: A semaphore probably isn't the best way to implement a concurrent queue. A Google search on [concurrent queue c++] is in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if `CreateSemaphore` returns valid handle, there is comment at [CreateSemaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686946%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that:

> Setting the maximum count value of a Semaphore to INFINITE will make
>   it's corresponding Handle invalid.